# How to disable antialiasing in Eclipse?

Tags: macos, eclipse, c++, anti-aliasing

My settings are

- OSX Mountain Lion
- java version "1.7.0_17"
- eclipse cpp 4.4.1
- Thunderbolt display

I have tried running in the terminal:

```
defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 20
```

and even

```
defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 40
```

and restarting eclipse everytime, but I could never get rid of antialiasing as you can see
on the picture below (with blue over white background).

With Netbeans 8.0 I have the exact same problem despite adding the options i found on the net

```
-J-Dswing.aatext=false

-J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=false
```

I've been struggling a lot with it, so thanks a lot in advance for your help.

[image]

NB: Unlike eclipse, netbeans and even the terminal, it seems that emacs doesn t have this problem as you can see on the picture below (with orange over dark background)

[image]

Comment: Strange! No answer!